# How to extract Eigen MatrixXd from numpy ndarray with Boost

Tags: python, numpy, boost-python

In Boost's documentation, the `extract` function is used to convert built-in python datatypes to c++ datatypes. I have a python function that returns a numpy ndarray and in my c++ code I want to convert it to an Eigen MatrixXd. So, I was wondering if it is possible to extract a non built-in python type to a non built-in c++ type.

Comment: A numpy ndarray _isn't_ a built-in Python datatype, it's a numpy class.

Comment: Thanks, I reworded the post...

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the conversion between the numpy ndarray and the c++ Eigen:::MatrixXd and register it in the boost python registry.

It looks like this

```
namespace py = boost::python
template <typename MatrixType>
struct pyToEigen {
  pyToEigen() {
    py::converter::registry::push_back(&convertible, &construct, py::type_id<MatrixType>());
   }
  static void* convertible(PyObject* obj_ptr) {
    // check for if object is convetible here
  }
  static void construct(PyObject* obj_ptr, py::converter::rvalue_from_python_stage1_data* data) {
    // Construct here
  }
}:
```

I wrote a header-only library that does the work: https://github.com/vsamy/pygen-converter
You just need to call `pygen::converter(Converters::All, true)` to bring several differents conversions.

One of the main drawback of this method is that it **copies** everything.